# Which verb is used for the word "activity" - "do" or "play"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

In an English test I had recently, there was this multiple choice question:

> There were lots of different activities for Jay to ... there.
>
> A - Make  B - Do  C - Play

There was no extra information for the exercise, just the word to complete.

I chose *do*, but it turns out both *do* and *play* were accepted.
Why is the word "play" accepted to complete this sentence?

Are they both correct? Why?
If there was a question on the SAT telling me to complete the sentence with the verb that best suits the sentence, which should I choose?

Comment: **Do**. You can do more things than play. *Different activities* implies a wide variety (e.g. paint, draw, read, play games, do puzzles, make things, exercise, whatever. If the sentence read *There were lots of different games/sports for Jay to ... there.* then the best answer would be *play*.

Comment: I'm surprised that _play_ was accepted. _Playing activities_ doesn't sound right to me, semantically.

Comment: It's the fault of Common Core. 'Activities to play' definitely does NOT sound natural, but we wouldn't want to mark someones answer 'wrong' for giving their best effort, now would we? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Play* is not accepted in this case.

For it to work, we would have to be able to rephrase it as a simpler clause, thus:

> *Jay made activities / Jay makes activities.
>
> Jay did activities / Jay does activities.
>
> *Jay played activities / Jay plays activities.

Syntactically they're all fine, but the first requires an object that makes sense with the meaning of *make* which suggests creation, so requires something he could "make". *Activities* would be strange here.

(It is perhaps in the list precisely because in some other languages there is a word that covers both this and also *do*, so some people with English as a second language will confuse them).

The third similarly requires an object that makes sense with *play*, and we would only allow this with certain nouns, such as games, musical instruments, tricks, or the names of specific cases of those.

Really, I'd say this is a worse choice than *make*.

I suspect this is simply a slip by the teacher.

I note that while I can't see the answers in the preview [here](http://books.google.ie/books?id=uYkInWmh34oC&pg=PA57&dq=%22There+were+lots+of+different+activities+for+Jay+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aUz7UpfJKOek7Qb6sYEQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22There%20were%20lots%20of%20different%20activities%20for%20Jay%20to%22&f=false), the phrasing of the question does definitely suggest one pick a single *best* answer. The implication is strong that there is one, and only one acceptable answer.